# Using glVertexAttribPointer to draw model in OpenGL 2.0 with shaders

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, vertex-shader, vertex-array

I've knocked up object orientated iOS app loosely based on the default template which uses OpenGLES 2.0 and also uses Shaders but I'm trying to load in a model where I used to call this:

```
#import "./sphere_model.h"
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, sphere_modelVerts);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, sphere_modelNormals);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, sphere_modelNumVerts);
```

The reason why I used that code above was because I converted my `.obj` file into a file I can include with all the arrays I need defined (see [obj2opengl](http://heikobehrens.net/2009/08/27/obj2opengl/)). Now, I'm not 100% but I read somewhere that `glVertexPointer` is deprecated and I'm struggling to get this working in my demo app. Currently I'm drawing this simple cube:

[image: cubey!]

The template where I took the OpenGL shader code from uses `glVertexAttribPointer` instead and the vertex array used is slightly different because it includes normals within the same array:

```
GLfloat gCubeVertexData[216] =
{
    // Data layout for each line below is:
    // positionX, positionY, positionZ,     normalX, normalY, normalZ,
    0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,         1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,         1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,         1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,          1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,         1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    ....
};
```

I use this code to draw the cube (after loading the shader file):

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(gCubeVertexData), gCubeVertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24, BUFFER_OFFSET(12));

glUseProgram(GetProgram());

glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTION_MATRIX], 1, 0, _modelViewProjectionMatrix.m);
glUniformMatrix3fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_NORMAL_MATRIX], 1, 0, _normalMatrix.m);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);

glDisableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);

glBindVertexArrayOES(0);
```

Now my question is, using Open GLES 2.0, is it possible to load in the vertices defined by `obj2opengl` I mentioned earlier using `glVertexAttribPointer` instead of `glVertexPointer` while still using the shader?

Here is some samples from one of the model files:

```
unsigned int sphere_modelNumVerts = 864;

float sphere_modelVerts [] = {
    -1.93077099209747e-18, 0.49025, 0.098,
    0.098, 0.49025, -1.78225014655151e-18,
    -1.93077099209747e-18, 0.5, -1.78225014655151e-18,
    -1.93077099209747e-18, 0.44725, 0.2235,
    0.11775, 0.4715, 0.11775,
    -1.93077099209747e-18, 0.49025, 0.098,
    ...
}

float sphere_modelNormals [] = {
    0, 0.980579906452681, 0.196119981290155,
    0.196119981290155, 0.980579906452681, 0,
    0, 1, 0,
    0, 0.894429190989163, 0.447209595499104,
    ...
}

float sphere_modelTexCoords [] = {
    0.75000, 0.0628300000000001,
    1, 0.0628300000000001,
    0.87500, 0,
    0.75000, 0.14758,
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use struct of arrays. The code sample that is drawing a cube is using interleaved vertex data. It is also called array of structures. This is a [recommended layout](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH107-SW10).

To support your data format simply create individual buffer for each attribute (sphere_modelVerts, sphere_modelNormals ...) and define attributes without offsets.

Comment: Excellent! I should have paid more attention to that doc previously! I got my model loaded! However just to check, by calling `glBuffer(..., sphere_modelVerts,...)` then `glBuffer(..., sphere_modelNormals, ...)` and calling without the offsets am I not using the recommended interleaved vertex data? Is this a particularly bad thing?

Comment: @ing0, This might degrade performance due to lack of memory locality (also mentioned in the article :)

Comment: Hi, yea that's what I thought, just wanted to confirm! I'll probably have to start looking for a different way to load objects! Thanks for you help anyway, got it working for now!